# Chrome create extention to avoid origin file // is not allowed by access-control-allow-origin

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am getting origin file // is not allowed by access-control-allow-origin. chrome
when calling an https//abc.com using xmlHttpRequest().
Works fine in IE10 but not in Chrome. I get the above error in Chrome. Searching online i saw I need to make a packaged extension and mention http://*/ in that file under 'permissions'. How to create this extension and install? Am i missing something, can somebody give a tutorial.

Comment: check this link please https://www.bionicspirit.com/blog/2011/03/24/cross-domain-requests.html

Answer (score 0):

Your solution definitely has nothing to do with creating a chrome extension. What you read with regards to that is only for those actually developing a Chrome extension and will not help you on your site. Read the link given by Satya in the comments. Here it is again:

[Cross Domain Requests](http://bionicspirit.com/blog/2011/03/24/cross-domain-requests.html)